# Gap between nav bar and background-image?

Tags: html, css

I have a gap between the bottom of my navigation bar and my background image. I have had a look at my code but I cant seem to fix it or find out what is wrong. Any help?

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="landingContent">
        <input type="checkbox" id="navbar-checkbox" class="navbar-checkbox">

    <nav id="middle" class="menu">
                    <li><a href="#" id="logo-nav"> < /> </a></li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" id="active">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

        <label for="navbar-checkbox" class="navbar-handle"></label>
    </nav>

    <div class="content-main">
        <h1>System</h1>
        <p>"A new look into technology"</p>
        <center>
        <div class="first"><button class="button" id="btn-nw" type="button" onclick="smoothScroll(document.getElementById('second'))"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></button></div>
    </center>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="otherContent">
    <h1 id="second">Services</h1>
    <br>

</div>





</body>
```

CSS: (I posted it all because I am not sure what is wrong)

```
*, body, html{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
html {
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
h1 { 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.landingContent{
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  background-image: url('../img/BG-2.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  }
.otherContent{
  margin: 0px;
  width:100vw;
  height:1000px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;

  }


.content-main p, h1{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    color: #F2F2F2;
}
.content-main h1{
    font-size: 120px;
}
.content-main p{
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.content-main{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 80px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}
.button{
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 60px;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.button:hover{
  opacity: 0.9;
}

button:focus {outline:0;}
/*Navigation CSS*/
#logo-nav {
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}


@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .menu {
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
}
.menu {
  padding: 0.5em;
  background: #323131;
  min-height: 2em;
  line-height: 1em;
  width: 100%;
}
.menu a{
    color: #5D5A5A;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu a:hover{
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
#active{
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.menu > ul {
  transition: max-height 0.25s linear;
}
.menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
}
.menu li {
  transition: visibility .25s linear;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .45em 1.0em;
  margin: 0 .3em;
  position: relative;
}

@media (min-width: 651px) {
  .menu li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    margin-top: 1px;
    left: -1px;
    right: -1px;
  }
  .menu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu li li {
    margin: -1px 0 0 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 650px) {
  .content-main{
    margin-top: 80px;
  }
  #logo-nav{
    visibility: visible;
  }
  .content-main h1{
    font-size: 45px;
  }
  .menu > ul {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 3.5em 0 1em;
  }
  .menu li {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    padding: 0.5em 0.6em;
    border: none;  }
  .menu li ul {
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
  }
  .menu .navbar-handle {
    display: block;
  }
  #navbar-checkbox:checked + .menu ul {
    max-height: 300px;
  }
  #navbar-checkbox:checked + .menu li {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  #navbar-checkbox:checked + .menu .navbar-handle,
  #navbar-checkbox:checked + .menu .navbar-handle:after,
  #navbar-checkbox:checked + .menu .navbar-handle:before {
    border-color: #aaa;
  }
}
.navbar-checkbox {
  display: none;
}
.navbar-handle {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 45px;
  padding: .5em 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 1.66666667em;
  border-top: 0.13333333em solid;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.navbar-handle:before,
.navbar-handle:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  content: ' ';
  border-top: 0.13333333em solid;
}
.navbar-handle:before {
  top: 0.37777778em;
}
.navbar-handle:after {
  top: 0.88888889em;
}
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.menu .navbar-handle {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  top: 0.7em;
  right: 12px;
  z-index: 10;
  color: white;
}

}
}
```

Comment: would be great if you setup a jsfiddle of this as it's pretty hard to fix from just looking at code

Answer (score 0):

You simply added too much margin in your `content-main` class.

```css
*, body, html{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
html {
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
h1 { 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.landingContent{
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  background-image: url('../img/BG-2.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  }
.otherContent{
  margin: 0px;
  width:100vw;
  height:1000px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;

  }


.content-main p, h1{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    color: #F2F2F2;
}
.content-main h1{
    font-size: 120px;
}
.content-main p{
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.content-main{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 58px; /*Your problem was here*/
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}
.button{
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 60px;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.button:hover{
  opacity: 0.9;
}

button:focus {outline:0;}
/*Navigation CSS*/
#logo-nav {
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}


@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .menu {
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
}
.menu {
  padding: 0.5em;
  background: #323131;
  min-height: 2em;
  line-height: 1em;
  width: 100%;
}
.menu a{
    color: #5D5A5A;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu a:hover{
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
#active{
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.menu > ul {
  transition: max-height 0.25s linear;
}
.menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
}
.menu li {
  transition: visibility .25s linear;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .45em 1.0em;
  margin: 0 .3em;
  position: relative;
}

@media (min-width: 651px) {
  .menu li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    margin-top: 1px;
    left: -1px;
    right: -1px;
  }
  .menu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu li li {
    margin: -1px 0 0 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 720px) { /* I changed this, too */
  .content-main{
    margin-top: 80px;
  }
  #logo-nav{
    visibility: visible;
  }
  .content-main h1{
    font-size: 45px;
  }
  .menu > ul {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 3.5em 0 1em;
  }
  .menu li {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    padding: 0.5em 0.6em;
    border: none;  }
  .menu li ul {
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
  }
  .menu .navbar-handle {
    display: block;
  }
  #navbar-checkbox:checked + .menu ul {
    max-height: 300px;
  }
  #navbar-checkbox:checked + .menu li {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  #navbar-checkbox:checked + .menu .navbar-handle,
  #navbar-checkbox:checked + .menu .navbar-handle:after,
  #navbar-checkbox:checked + .menu .navbar-handle:before {
    border-color: #aaa;
  }
}
.navbar-checkbox {
  display: none;
}
.navbar-handle {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 45px;
  padding: .5em 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 1.66666667em;
  border-top: 0.13333333em solid;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.navbar-handle:before,
.navbar-handle:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  content: ' ';
  border-top: 0.13333333em solid;
}
.navbar-handle:before {
  top: 0.37777778em;
}
.navbar-handle:after {
  top: 0.88888889em;
}
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.menu .navbar-handle {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  top: 0.7em;
  right: 12px;
  z-index: 10;
  color: white;
}

}
}
```

```html
<div class="landingContent">
        <input type="checkbox" id="navbar-checkbox" class="navbar-checkbox">

    <nav id="middle" class="menu">
                    <li><a href="#" id="logo-nav"> < /> </a></li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" id="active">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

        <label for="navbar-checkbox" class="navbar-handle"></label>
    </nav>

    <div class="content-main">
        <h1>System</h1>
        <p>"A new look into technology"</p>
        <center>
        <div class="first"><button class="button" id="btn-nw" type="button" onclick="smoothScroll(document.getElementById('second'))"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></button></div>
    </center>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="otherContent">
    <h1 id="second">Services</h1>
    <br>

</div>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```